# Can't get my assert current activity to work

Tags: android, robotium

I have 2 activities, the first one is the startup one which in it's create method causes the second one to be launched, always.
My Robolectric tests pass fine

Activity

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override    

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.loginview);

    Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);
    startActivity( intent );
}
```

I know my activity works fine cause it launches in my device and on the emulator

My Robolectric tests

```
public void testLoginFirstTime() throws Exception 
{
    LoginActivity activity = new LoginActivity();        
    activity.onCreate(null);
    assertThat(activity, new StartedMatcher(MainActivity.class));        
}
```

My Robotium test

```
public void setUp() throws Exception {
    solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), getActivity());
}


public void testLoginFirstTime() throws Exception 
{
    solo.assertCurrentActivity("Expected MainActivity to launch", MainActivity.class);
}
```

What is wrong with my robotium assertion? it always thinks the current activity is login one even though as I watch the emulator/device I can see that Robotium does actually launch the MainActivity but it doesn't appear to know that the new activity has been launched.
Edit: Meant to say if I add a button to my login view and launch the new activty via a button click then Robotium performs the click and detects the new activity has been launched ok.

Edit:
Looks like its a Robotium limitation
http://groups.google.com/group/robotium-developers/browse_thread/thread/79a70038c16e35e6
However it still leaves me with the issue of how to test my app with robotium the same way as a user will use it,  ie,  not cheating and starting in a different activity :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to use the constructor solo = new Solo(Instrumentation instrumentation) and then after you have created the Solo object you call getActivity() in order to start the first Activity. Then it will work.