# Using Robotium, Unable to intent to next activity?

Tags: android, android-intent, robotium

How to write test case to call next activity using Robotium.
Below Code i was tried but have an issue comparison error,

```
public void testCaseValidLogin() throws Exception {
solo.enterText(loginUserName,Username);
       solo.enterText(loginPassword, Password);
        solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.loginsuccess));

         solo.assertCurrentActivity("Launch FileList Class", FileListActivityTest.class);}
```

Once i click login button, its intent to next activity test case class but i get comparison error in  that line

> [solo.assertCurrentActivity("Launch FileList Class",
>   FileListActivityTest.class);]

please help me... thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

> > solo = new Solo(Instrumentation instrumentation)
> >
> > getActivity(), this will start the 1st Activity.

Reference: [Can't get my assert currrent activity to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7849938/cant-get-my-assert-currrent-activity-to-work)

Answer (score 0):

Assertion error is because the code `solo.assertCurrentActivity("Launch FileList Class", 
FileListActivityTest.class);` is executed before new Activity is launched.
Instead `solo.waitForActivity(FileListActivityTest.class);` should be the right way to verify is FileListActivityTest activity is launched.

Comment: Thanks for your post. I have two screens one is login screen in that i have register button, test case for Register solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.account));
    solo.waitForActivity("CreateAccountActivityTest");

  solo.assertCurrentActivity("create Account Activity launch", CreateAccountActivityTest.class); In CreateAccopuntActivity test class look like this solo.enterText(firstName, "xxx");
  solo.enterText(emailAddress, "zzzz"); solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.reg_btnSubmit)); Once i click submit button details are registered. HOW TO INTENT TO CREATEACCOUNTTEST case class

Comment: You don't have to fire any intent from your test case. Your app code should take care of intent firing. Test case should only validate whether intent was fired or not. Once solo.clickOnView(solo.getView(R.id.account)) executes, the intent to launch CreateAccountActivityTest, all you do is wait for the activity to be launched and then assert it as expected.